# Image resizing with preserve ratio to full scene

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I'm currently writing a program where I want to have a background image, which resizes with a preserved ratio, when the scene is being resized as well. I'm using SceneBuilder for Java 8 to build the fxml and I have already bound the image properties to my AnchorPane properties like this:

```java
imageBackground.fitHeightProperty().bind(anchorPaneBackground.heightProperty());
imageBackground.fitWidthProperty().bind(anchorPaneBackground.widthProperty());
```

The issue I'm having right now is that due to the preserved ratio my image won't resize to the full scene any more if the ratio cannot be preserved.

How can I "oversize" the image, so that the image is always shown on the full scene? Do I have to use a listener of some sort or am I overlooking something?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Rather than using an `ImageView`, set the background of some `Region` (maybe the root of the scene) as your image. Then set its size to ["cover"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html). You can do this in code or CSS.

Comment: 1. Please define the required behavior: do you want to maintain the image aspect ratio **or** stretch it to fit the scene ? These may contradict.  2. Post [mcve]

Comment: @c0der as I stated in my question already, the aspect ratio should be preserved and **not** strech.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you. I will not do it any more.

Comment: you did miss the second sentence in @c0der comment: do as suggested on the referenced help page ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're goals are:

1. Preserve aspect ratio of the image.
2. Cover the entire area with the image (i.e. no gaps on any side).

Rather than using an `ImageView` I recommend setting [the background](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) of your `Region` to be your image. You can then set [the size](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html) of the background image to [cover](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html#isCover()), which will:

> [...] scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area.

Setting the background is possible programmatically, via CSS, or via FXML.

In Java:

```
Image image = ...;
BackgroundImage bgImage = new BackgroundImage(
        image,                                                 // image
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,                            // repeatX
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,                            // repeatY
        BackgroundPosition.CENTER,                             // position
        new BackgroundSize(-1, -1, false, false, false, true)  // size
);
anchorPaneBackground.setBackground(new Background(bgImage));
```

In CSS (see [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)):

```css
/* Or whatever ID/style class you give the target region */
#achorPaneBackground {
    -fx-background-image: url("your/image/path");
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In FXML (can't promise this is as concise as possible):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Background?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/12" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <background>
        <Background>
            <images>
                <BackgroundImage repeatX="NO_REPEAT" repeatY="NO_REPEAT">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="your/image/path"/>
                    </image>
                    <position>
                        <BackgroundPosition fx:constant="CENTER"/>
                    </position>
                    <size>
                        <BackgroundSize cover="true"/>
                    </size>
                </BackgroundImage>
            </images>
        </Background>
    </background>

</AnchorPane>
```

*Note: I don't believe you can set the background of a `Region` in Scene Builder (except by adding a stylesheet). Please correct me if I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the ratio you can use [`ImageView.setPreserveRatio()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setPreserveRatio-boolean-) to prevent stretching of the image:

```
imageBackground.setPreserveRatio(true);
```

From the docs:

> Indicates whether to preserve the aspect ratio of the source image when scaling to fit the image within the fitting bounding box.
>
> If set to true, it affects the dimensions of this ImageView in the following way
>
> - If only fitWidth is set, height is scaled to preserve ratio
> - If only fitHeight is set, width is scaled to preserve ratio
> - If both are set, they both may be scaled to get the best fit in a width by height rectangle while preserving the original aspect ratio
>
> If unset or set to false, it affects the dimensions of this ImageView in the following way
>
> - If only fitWidth is set, image's view width is scaled to match and height is unchanged;
> - If only fitHeight is set, image's view height is scaled to match and height is unchanged;
> - If both are set, the image view is scaled to match both.